# Custom User Flow not logging the user in, returns to AzureADB2C/Account/Error

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I have created a User Flow in Azure AD B2C which is being used to register new users. When a new user registers they are being redirected to the AzureADB2C/Account/Error page of my site and they are not logged in. If I then use the sing_in_up policy link the user is then signed in without having to authenticate. I believe I am having an issue with reading the returned credentials after creating the account but I am not too sure.

Here is my link that is directing the user to the signup page:

```
<a class="btn btn-light mx-1" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignUp">
   <strong>Sing Up Free</strong>
</a>
```

This is the controller method:

```
public IActionResult SignUp()
{
    return this.Challenge(
        new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, "B2C_1_sign_up");
}
```

This is my OpenIdConnectionOptions:

```
private Action<OpenIdConnectOptions> GetOpenIdSignUpOptions(string policy)
        => options =>
        {
            options.MetadataAddress =
                "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[Domain].onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=" + policy;
            options.ClientId = "[***]";
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
            options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout/" + policy;
            options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
            options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/";
        };
```

Where [Domain] = the Azure AD B2C domain and [***] = the Azure AD B2C ClientId.

This is my service configuration:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureADB2C(options =>
        Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options)
        );

services.AddAuthentication(
    options => options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddOpenIdConnect("B2C_1_sign_up", GetOpenIdSignUpOptions("B2C_1_sign_up"))
    .AddCookie();
```

The B2C_1_sign_up_in and custom B2C_1_sign_up policies are Identical with the exception of the B2C_1_sign_up_in containing the Unified sign up or sign in page. Any help troubleshooting this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the journey complete when launching it from the portal using the “run now” link? Test it with a reply url for https://jwt.ns registered in the app Registration.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few points to check:

- Please ensure that you have tested the custom sign up policy from Azure AD B2C blade from the portal, Check if it working fine or not.
- Make sure to configure CORS for the customized page and the location where you have stored.
  Validate that you're ready by doing the following:

  - Go to the www.test-cors.org website, and then paste the URL in the 
    Remote URL box.
  - Click Send Request.

If you receive an error, make sure that your CORS settings are correct. You might also need to clear your browser cache or open an in-private browsing session by pressing Ctrl+Shift+P.

- Also please make sure to change the base policy with right content definition.

Please refer this link for [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-ui-customization-custom).